# What should I do before push my branch to remote?

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-flow

Before creating the new branch I did:

```
git fetch upstream 
git checkout master 
git rebase upsteam/master 
git push origin master
```

So now my local and my remote origin are up to date with the upstream.
I created a new branch:

```
git checkout -b fix
```

Worked on this for a few days, several commits. What should I do now before pushing it to my origin and requesting a pull request? There is work done on the upstream/master branch. Should I fetch and rebase once again?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to do so, yes. It will ensure that there are no new conflicts and that your changes work with the latest upstream code. This usually also increases the probability of getting merged, especially if there were merge conflicts otherwise.

You don't necessarily have to update your master branch though. You can directly do on your `fix` branch

```
git pull --rebase upstream/master
```

Then resolve potential conflicts, retest your changes and then push and open the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge `upstream/master`. Just make sure there is no conflict with `upstream/master` and your branch (`fix`) is updated. Now push your branch to remote (`origin/fix`) and create a pull request.

```
$ git fetch upstream    
$ git pull upstream master

$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

For **origin** remote, you can push fix branch directly (`git push origin fix`) and also can create a PR if you want to merge fix branch into master branch.

For **upstream** remote, if upstream/master updated, origin/master will not automatically update. If you want origin/fix branch is based on the top of upstream/master branch, you should do:

```
git checkout fix
git pull upstream master --rebase
```

This will make fix branch on the top of upstream/master branch.

If the first PR is not approved yet, you just need to use `git push origin fix` push to origin, the PR will automatically contain the changes from upstream/master branch.